# Tandy CoCo 2 text adventure game where you have to evade zombies

Tags: story-identification, video-games, zombie-apocalypse

This is one of those things where the details are on the tip of my tongue. On our Tandy Color Computer 2, somewhere in the late 1980s to the early 1990s, one of the games was a text adventure where you had to survive zombies. I never made it all the way through (there were a lot of ways to die), but my memories:

- The game started with you in a stopped car on a foggy road. Maybe you'd just run out of gas? You were unaware of the zombies at the time.
- There was a zombie with a leather jacket (probably supposed to be some sort of greaser character) who would kill you if you hung around the car too long. I think maybe he had some sort of razor or knife with which he'd kill you?
- There was a zombie who was some sort of groundskeeper or maintenance guy who either would kill you with a screwdriver, or was killed by the same. That screwdriver was a collectable inventory item
- There was a zombie who was a young boy, maybe an altar boy. I remember that, early in the game, if you got past a cemetery fence early enough, he would try to scale it, and instead impale himself on the spikes. And yes, there were ways in which you could do things wrong and he could kill you.
- I want to say there was something involving a woman with a sweater who turned into a zombie, maybe a girlfriend from the beginning? Again, it was possible to die from encountering her.

My vague memory of my typical run of the game was that I'd spend a turn or two searching the car for various supplies, then head away from the car and encounter the cemetery gates. I think it required the screwdriver to bypass the gates, and a turn or two later, the altar boy showed up and impaled himself (I don't think it incapacitated him. You could search him for another item, but if you weren't careful, you'd get bitten). Then... I don't remember the details other than that you headed into the cemetery and encountered other zombies.

I don't *think* this was one of the games that my brother typed in from *Rainbow* magazine. I have a vague memory of running into a walkthrough in one of the text files on a random diskette, said walkthroughs also including one for the *Yellow Submarine* game, *Dallas Quest*, and *To Preserve Quandic*, but unlike those games, I think it was entirely text, no primitive graphics to enhance the scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And, after I mentioned walkthroughs, I decided to do a search to see if maybe that walkthough might be the key, which brought me [here](https://colorcomputerarchive.com/repo/Documents/Walkthroughs/), which includes [a walkthough for *Night of the Living Dead*](https://colorcomputerarchive.com/repo/Documents/Walkthroughs/Night%20of%20the%20Living%20Dead%20Walkthrough%20(Adventure%20Novel%20Software).txt).

> "OPEN GLOVE BOX"
> "GET KNIFE"
> "TURN ON RADIO"
> "TURN OFF RADIO"
> "EXIT CAR"
> "OPEN TRUNK"
> "GET HOSE"

....

> "EXAMINE CHOIRBOY"
> "GO DOOR"
> "ATTACK CARETAKEER WITH SHOVEL"
> "TWIST SHOVEL"
> "SEARCH CARETAKERS BODY"

According to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/retrobattlestations/comments/59ydk6/comment/d9cavge/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), it was a 1988 release by Savage Software, and there was a contest to find a solution.

> For this 1988 Savage Software release the company offered a US$500.00 prize to the first one to submit a solution transcript of the adventure. Never heard of anyone winning it although the promo info found in the game stated that if no solution was provided by a certain deadline, the winner would be picked from the registered owners (they would have had to submit their register cards to be eligible).

Comment: Well done! I love games with prizes - I really need to read all those blog entries about *Alkemstone* some day...